# Do you recognize this plumbing logo?

Tags: plumbing

I am trying to replace a seal on a bathtub drain.

The central screen on the drain has a hole pattern, but no central screw. Looking through the holes I can only see the cross on the bottom and the smooth walls of the basket. I can not see any clips. It does not pop out with moderate force. Is it possibly threaded or is it likely frozen?

[image]

If someone recognized this logo on the overflow plate (toggle type drain) or was familiar with how this drain screen is designed to be removed it would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Most are threaded someway, but over time can become hard to remove.  If not too tight, almost anything(needle nose pliers) struck into the holes should turn it, don't force too much.

Comment: Also just edit your post and add the picture. Scrolling is easy, and missing information would make your question harder to answer.